# Updating Prestashop database

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, prestashop

I've had a performance question regarding Prestashop and database updates.
I'm trying to update the stock on a Prestashop database set on Mysql innoDB.
The problem is the script takes around 3 minutes to run the script for 20000 entities.

I'm using the "reference" field in the product table to select ID's corresponding to that reference. then use the ID on the Prestashop function:

```
StockAvailable::setQuantity((int)$id, null, (int)$stock, null)
```

The select query for the ID's is as follows:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id_product FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'product WHERE reference = '. $reference
```

I've already set the reference in the database as index, it did speed it up somewhat but not that much.

For some better context this script has to run every 15 minutes to update the stock.

Comment: So you are calling `setQuantity` 20k times? That probably means a single database query each time – and that means you can index all you want, it’s likely to not do any good at all. (And indexes usually increase _read_ performance, whereas _write_ operations might actually be slowed down, because the index has to be updated after data is inserted/updated.) Depending on where your data is coming from, it might be better to do this in “pure” SQL, rather than calling a method for every single product. (But before implementing anything like this, check carefully what the method actually does.)

Comment: I've got it significantly faster doing 1 select query on the whole product list  now it runs on 0.68 min.. It still takes some time but a lot less.

Comment: If you are "updating", why are you "selecting"??